# $X=Y$ almost surely iff $\forall A\in \mathcal{G}\int_AXdP=\int_AYdP$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space with $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$. Let $X,Y$ be $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, and integrable. Then, how does one prove that

$X=Y$ almost surely iff $\forall A\in \mathcal{G} \int_AXdP=\int_AYdP$?

Here's my try: 
$\int_AXdP=\int_AYdP \Leftrightarrow \int_AX-YdP=\int_A(X-Y)1_{[X\geq Y]}+(Y-X)1_{[X< Y]}dP=0$

For $A=[Y\geq X]$, we get $\int_{[X\geq Y]}X-YdP=0$ which implies, by nonnegativity of $X-Y$ on A, $P(X=Y)=P(X\geq Y)$ or $P(X\geq Y)=0$

For $A=[Y<X]$, we get $\int_{[X<Y]}Y-XdP=0$ which implies, by nonnegativity of $X-Y$ on A, $P(X=Y)=P(X< Y)$ or $P(X< Y)=0$

So, we get $$(P(X\geq Y)=0 \ \land \ P(X=Y)=P(X< Y)) \ \lor \ (P(X< Y)=0 \ \land \ P(X=Y)=P(X\geq Y)) $$

which gives $P(X=Y)=1$.

I can choose A as above since the sum of measurable functions is also measurable $[X>Y]=[X-Y>0]$

Is this a proper proof?

Comment: Who is $\mathcal B$, and what is meant by "Let $X,Y$ be random variables in $\mathcal G$?" That $X$ and $Y$ are $\sigma(G)$-measurable?

Comment: @Math1000 I've corrected the typos.